# Docusign login prompt and social media icons

Tags: docusignapi

When completing an envelope, if the recipient already has a docusign account I noticed that he/she gets a docusign login prompt complete with social media icons.  We are using docusign in a healthcare setting where social media icons don't fit and can produce confusion and fear among some users.  We have the social media settings turned off in the signing resources XML file.  That seems to work for recipients that don't already have a docusign account, but if the recipient does have one, the social media icons still appear.

Is there a way to disable both the login prompt and the social media icons for recipients that already have a docusign account?

Comment: I've never found a way.  We're in the same position as you, would prefer to have more control over the "your signer happens to have a DocuSign account" scenarios!

Comment: If they have a DocuSign account and have completed at least one document so far they would be used to the social icons that show up at the end.  Obviously not ideal but are the users who are concerned/getting confused about the icons users who have accounts or ones that do not?

Comment: The social media icons only show for signers who have accounts.  Is there no way to disable the login prompt and social media icons for signers who have accounts?

Comment: Looks like the short answer is 'no' - since these signers have their own DocuSign accounts, it is not up to the sender to limit what the signers login options should be - at least thats what i believe the rationale to be.